# Which significance test for investigating an improvement over time?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures

Context:

- I am investigating a dataset that has the ID of a subject, the number of miles they travelled on a specific day, a grouping category for 50 users, and a date for when they recorded the data.
- For each user, we know the number of miles the user ran.
- The grouping category is something like "Before enhancement x" and "After enhancement x".
- For each user, we have a number of measurements of the miles they ran in the "Before" and "After" category. However, for each user the number of data points we have in the before and after group is not the same. e.g. User 1 has 35 measurements in the "Before group", and 40 measurements in the "After group", while User 2 has 31 measurements in the "Before group" and 38 measurements in the "After group".
  This data looks something like:

  ```
  Subject     Miles    Group
  User 1      5          A
  User 1      6          A
  User 1      6          B
  User 2      11         A
  User 2      8          B
  User 2      13         B
  User 2      13         B
  ```

I am investigating whether there is a significant improvement in the number of miles run between the before and after group when the user has taken "enhancement x".

My first thought was the use of a paired t-test. I know I will need to check the normality of the miles run to use the test, but I am unsure how to best approach analysing this dataset if the assumptions are satisfied. Is it valid to take the mean of the miles run in the "Before" and "After" group across the subjects and then find the different based on that? This seems problematic as there is not a 1-1 matching between the before and after group.

If the paired t-test is not valid for this investigation, are there other tests that would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

You can used a paired t-tests on the individual users. Taking multiple measurements that vary in number, before and after a "treatment" (or equivalent) is common.

Create a data set which has one entry for the average of User X under A, and one entry for the average of User X under B.  Run a paired t-test on the two columns.

```
Subject     Average Miles   Average Miles
              Group A         Group B
User 1         5.5               6.0
User 2         11.0             11.33
...
```

This gives you what you want.

Make sure the other assumptions of a paired t-test are satisfied (other than that the data is paired).

There are factors that can affect the results. What if it is considerably hotter on all the B days?  That gets into study design.